# Vuejs + Axios -> API Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, axios, get

tengo un problema con el resultado de una consulta en Axios.get ()

```
 showSolicitudes: function () {
      this.isLoading = true;
      axios.get("/api.solicitudes").then((response) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.info(response.data);
        this.solicitudes = response.data;
      });
    },
```

/api.solicitudes en el navegador devuelve lo siguiente al igual que en la solapa network al hacer la consulta:

```
[{"id": 1, "created_at": "2021-03-30 13:10:26", "updated_at": "2021-04-10 11:30:06", "uuid_solicitud": "70641250-9172 -11eb-9da6-5188f414b36a "," uuid_usuario ":" ee923ea0-3a1c-11eb-9e85-c79b5ee983fa "," nombre ":" Adelanto de Sueldo "," monto ": 5000," cuotas ": 1," interesAnual ": 500, "estado": "3", "uuid_comercial": "1", "motivo": "Solicitud Web"}, {"id": 2, "created_at": "2021-04-10 20:38:45 "," updated_at ":" 2021-04-25 12:44:59 "," uuid_solicitud ":" e3b17f00-9a55-11eb-9b16-a7c514f4a9f1 "," uuid_usuario ":" ee923ea0-3a1c-11eb-9e85-c79b5ee983fa , "nombre": "Adelanto de Sueldo", "monto ": 5000," cuotas ": 1," interesAnual ": 500," estado ":" 3 "," uuid_comercial ":" 1 "," motivo ":" Solicitud Web "}]
```

Pero en el console.log (response) el valor de "estado" siempre me lo muestra en "0"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda,

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a todos!...

El problema se encontraba en el botón:

```
<button
 :enable="(solicitud.estado = 0)"
  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
  @click.prevent="cancelarSolicitud(solicitud.uuid_solicitud)"
>
```

Esta linea...

```
:enable="(solicitud.estado = 0)"
```

Estaba asignado el valor 0, lo modifique de la siguiente manera y funciona correctamente.

```
<button
     :disabled="!(solicitud.estado == 0)"
      class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
      @click.prevent="cancelarSolicitud(solicitud.uuid_solicitud)"
    >
```

Saludos.